# Rails method not recognised

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm working through a book on Rails that shows how to build a blog application. I've just added functionality for adding comments to blog posts, and Rails is throwing an error that I can't fix.

According rails, the method "published" in the following line isn't defined:

```
errors.add(:article_id, "is not published yet") if article && !article.published?
```

Tracing this through, I found that my article model contains that line

```
scope :published, lambda { where("articles.published_at IS NOT NULL") }
```

As a Rails noob, I'm not entirely sure what "scope" means in this context, but I am guessing that it defines a method that can be called on an article by calling `article.published?`. Am I right?

From what I've read online it seems like this problem might be something to do with the book I'm working from being written for Rails 4.0, while I am using Rails 4.2.0. What do I need to change in this line to get it to work with Rails 4.2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is not related to the Rails version you're working with, you're simply calling the method on the wrong object.

first off, notice that there is a difference between `published` and `published?`. The second has a question mark.

The [`scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope) method defines a class method to filter results, and it would therefore be available on the class. e.g.

```
@articles = Article.published.where()...
```

You're working with an *instance*, though, and probably want to define an instance method like:

```
def published?
  published_at.present?
end
```

Comment: Thank you! You're completely correct, it turns out that I had missed the part of the book that had added *precisely* that method.